# How to check if the browsed file is .xlsx or .csv?

Tags: python

I am using openpyxl module, but now it turns out that it doesnot support csv format. So, How can I differentiate whether the file incoming is .xlsx or .csv format

Comment: Ultimately, the only thing that defines a file as being in a particular format is the ability to parse it as such. Extensions are conventional, but arbitrary. Just because a file as a `.csv` extension doesn't mean it actually *is* a CSV file, and just because a file *doesn't* have the `.csv` extension doesn't mean it isn't a CSV file.

Comment: I guess you could check to see if the xlsx magic number is at the start...

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way would be to check the first four bytes of the file's contents in binary mode to check for a zip-alike file.

`xlsx` files (and other archive files) have `50 4B 03 04` (hex) as their "magic number" - see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) for a list of many other so-called "magic numbers".

In Python, we can represent `50 4B 03 04` as `b'PK\x03\x04'`, so we can create a function to load the file, and read the first four bytes, and check if they are this magic number:

```
filename1 = "test.xlsx"
if is_xlsx(filename1):
    print(filename1, "is an Excel file!")
    # load it openpyxl
else:
    print(filename1, "is an CSV file!")
    # load it with csv


filename2 = "test.csv"
if is_xlsx(filename2):
    print(filename2, "is an Excel file!")
    # load it openpyxl
else:
    print(filename2, "is an CSV file!")
    # load it with csv
```

Output (perhaps unpsurprisingly) :

```
test.xlsx is an Excel file!
test.csv is an CSV file!
```

Comment: xlsx files (and other archive files) have 50 4B 03 04 (hex) as their "magic number" - this is the correct answer

Comment: ```def is_xslx(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        first_four_bytes = f.read()[:4]
    return first_four_bytes == b'PK\x03\x04'
```

Comment: I found this issue helpful as I had a similar issue where a vendor was providing .xls files, but some of them were actually xlsx files. I did use the helpful function @m_ocean provided but changed f.read()[:4] to f.read(4) which speeds up performance a bit, especially if the files are large, or the disk is slow.  Note the function is named differently than the one EdWard used in his example.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have a filename, then you can use:

```
".xlsx" in filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Load it in `try:..except:..` At least in case of xlsx you can be quite confident that if it's failing, then it's not xlsx. CSV is so primitive a format, that almost everything can be treated as such, but I think that's the maximum that you can squeeze out of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in OSX/Linux you can use the file command.

file sample.xlsx 
sample.xlsx: Microsoft Excel 2007+

file sample.csv 
sample.csv: ASCII text

if you are on Windows you can install 
https://git-scm.com/download